# BPMN switch process owners between different entities

Tags: process, pool, bpmn, owner

For an assignment on BPMN in university, i have to model the following:

"In the bustling world of American universities, the journey of student enrollment is an intricate danceof administrative finesse and strategic decision-making. Unlike their Western European counterparts,where students often gain immediate acceptance, American universities set the stage for a moresuspenseful and selective process, where each applicant must navigate a series of critical steps tosecure their academic future.The adventure begins with the student's identity verification, a crucial first act that unfolds eitherthrough a personal visit to the university's enrollment office or via a high-tech form on the university'swebsite. Digital applicants face the challenge of validating their identities with digital signatures, amodern-day rite of passage into higher education (and a misstep here could swiftly lead to anencounter with the university's fraud department).Once past the gates of identity verification, a new or existing academic profile is linked to the student,marking the student's official entry into the enrollment arena. The next scene sees students declaringtheir academic aspirations, choosing from a kaleidoscope of faculties, degrees, and courses — adecision that could shape their entire future.The plot thickens as students submit personal details, SAT scores (if required), recommendations, andpast academic laurels. This information-gathering phase is a race against time, with students (2 weeks)and institutions (1 month) given tight deadlines to weave together the tapestry of the applicant'sacademic persona. Any delay in this critical phase could trigger in total two reminders and a graceperiod of 3 months in total. Otherwise, this is the end of the road for the hopeful applicant.Once the curtain rises on all the required information, the university applies its unique alchemy ofadmission rules. These rules are a complex mix of academic unit availability, the applicant's profile,and other mysterious criteria that could either open doors or lead to a polite but firm rejection.Rejections are communicated far and wide, sometimes even reaching the ears of parents (only forminors) and scholarship sponsors.For the lucky few who pass this test, a new challenge awaits: the selection process. Here, theuniversity's faculty becomes the judge and jury, deciding who among the admitted will actually claimtheir spot in the hallowed halls of learning. Success in this round means jubilation and acceptance;failure, however, is not the end, as students can reapply for a different academic unit.In this world, the freedom to cancel one’s application looms large, but beware — a cancellationwithout a good reason (like a family tragedy or pregnancy) could lead to an automatic rejection in thefollowing year.Students may apply for scholarships. Hopeful students apply through a government web portal,triggering a flurry of data requests to local authorities and educational institutions (grace period 2weeks, reminder after 1 week). Should any piece of the puzzle be missing, students face the prospectof starting over. Upon a positive evaluation, the installment amounts are calculated. To approve thescholarship, the installments must be less than $200 per month (with an exception if the student canprove they have a steady job, then the amount can go up to $300). This exception must be requested.Applications for a $300 installment must be approved by a supervisor. If the scholarship cannot beapproved, then we notify the student via email. Once the application passes the expert team's scrutiny and meets the financial criteria, a scholarship contract is drafted. The clock starts ticking for the studentto sign this contract within a month, lest the opportunity vanishes into thin air.With the contract signed and funds disbursed to the academic institution, students embark on theirjourney of monthly repayments. But beware, for those who falter in their repayments (2 months delay)may find themselves entangled in the finance department's dunning procedure.This entire enrollment odyssey is a blend of high stakes, strict timelines, and rigorous evaluations, allpart of the thrilling and daunting quest for higher education in the competitive landscape of American universities."

Now i spilt this in 3 processes: the student enrollment process, grant scholarschip process and the monthly repayment process. However, it seems that the process owner of the enrollment process is the university, while the owner of the other two processes is the government. Is is possible to switch the process owner to a different entity when modeling in BPMN?

Many thanks!

Keanu